# How to modifying a method of a class before posting it to the database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three fields a start_time:time , end_time:time and total_min:decimal fields. The user inputs the start_time and the end_time which are used to calculate the total minutes spent before saving it to the database (sq-lite). How do i calculate that total_min before posting it ?

```
    class CreateInternets < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :internets do |t|
         t.time :start_time
         t.time :end_time
         t.decimal :total_min
         t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use before_save callback by ActiveRecord.

```
before_save :update_total_min

def update_total_min
     total_min = end_time - start_time
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic with `Time`'s.  You can add this line to your `Internet#create` action:

```
 @internet.total_min = params[:start_time] - params[:end_time] / 60
```

Or using `strong_params`:

```
 @internet.total_min = internet_params[:start_time] - internet_params[:end_time] / 60
```

Make sure to whitelist the attributes in your controller:

```
 private
   def internet_params
     params.require(:internet).permit(:start_time, :end_time)
   end
```

Comment: After i insert it in the controller/create action it returns an error undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That sounds like you did not get params[:start_time] to submit from the form.  You are trying to use the - operator on a nil value.